# How to use faker to insert date and time separately in laravel factory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, faker

I am trying to create a model factory for an events table where I need to input the date and time separately. But every time I do a db:seed it gives me the error:

Exception trace:

1   Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize("03-06-2010")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php:697

2   Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar::Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars{closure}("03-06-2010", "date")
      [internal]:0

In my EventFactory.php file I am using

```
'date' => $faker->date($format = 'm-d-Y', $min = 'now'),
'time' => $faker->time($format = 'h:i', $min = 'now'),
```

Comment: try `'date' => $faker->date('m-d-Y','now'),
'time' => $faker->time('h:i', 'now'),`

Comment: Nope. Getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Carbon` for this. For example,

```
$date = Carbon::parse(now())->format('Y.m.d');
$time = Carbon::parse(now())->format('H:i:s');
```

I hope this will help.